# test for micronaut missing runtime dependencies

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, jvm, micronaut

I've had a bug appear a few times where micronaut is missing a dependency at runtime, this only shows up when the app is running. Is there a way to test for these missing dependencies in a unit test? I would basically need to walk all code paths in order to activate the JVM looking for classes I think.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to test for these missing dependencies in a unit test?

There will be for some specific kinds of dependencies, but not one in general no.

> I would basically need to walk all code paths in order to activate the
> JVM looking for classes I think.

That would not necessarily be sufficient.  There are a lot of things related to required dependencies that can be affected by the runtime environment (like OS environment variables, etc.).  The dependencies that you could tease out by walking code paths mostly (not entirely) will be identified at compile time.